# ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE `beneficiary_change_request` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aadhaar_application_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_line1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_line2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_line3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_line4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_line5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `election_card_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_address_line1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_address_line2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_address_line3` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_address_line4` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_address_line5` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_father_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_mother_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_occu_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_rel_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_spouse_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `monthly_income` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mother_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mstatus_id` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'S',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nat_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `occu_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_proof` longblob,
  `other_proof_file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_proof_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pincode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rationcard_proof` longblob,
  `rationcard_proof_file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_for_change` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rel_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `spouse_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `beneficiary_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taluk_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `approval_comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_verification_comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verification_comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `beneficiary_member_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_of_cylinder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IX_BENEFICIARYMEMBER_BENEFID` (`beneficiary_id`),
  KEY `FK_prupdn5u1px3g6gicjc5t0bc3` (`district_id`),
  KEY `FK_s1bjfnmuugyccqnoew8wmty2d` (`taluk_id`),
  KEY `FK_pcwwq9qtydnm8f0a9nh0i69rg` (`village_id`),
  KEY `FK_5jksn8cljflohv2du2hgia0qa` (`card_type_id`),
  KEY `FK_2pkls25f9a7dkgiftjn4ko033` (`beneficiary_member_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2pkls25f9a7dkgiftjn4ko033` FOREIGN KEY (`beneficiary_member_id`) REFERENCES `beneficiary_member` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_5jksn8cljflohv2du2hgia0qa` FOREIGN KEY (`card_type_id`) REFERENCES `card_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_b71nd0q2vollyl3ycay3o1bdq` FOREIGN KEY (`beneficiary_id`) REFERENCES `beneficiary` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_pcwwq9qtydnm8f0a9nh0i69rg` FOREIGN KEY (`village_id`) REFERENCES `village` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_prupdn5u1px3g6gicjc5t0bc3` FOREIGN KEY (`district_id`) REFERENCES `district` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_s1bjfnmuugyccqnoew8wmty2d` FOREIGN KEY (`taluk_id`) REFERENCES `taluk` (`id`)
) ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER AUTO_INCREMENT=286 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

when iam createing table this

> ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the
>   used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 14000. This includes storage
>   overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or
>   BLOBs

Comment: Can you format your question please?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Is there something about the error message you don't understand?  It seems quite clear to me.